# Flutter & Swift : How do I implement EventChannel or FlutterEventChannel?

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, listener

So I was try to bridge a listener from iOS Swift. So far I have setup a few things in Dart and Swift. But I'm not sure what to do next. Please give me some guide.

Dart

```
static const eventChannel = EventChannel("co.auth-number.key");

  static Stream get authStream {
    return eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream();
  }
```

Swift

```
var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?
// ------ ///

override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        self.certTransfer?.delegate = self
        
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        
        let event = FlutterEventChannel(name: K.Listener.authNumberKey, binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        
        event.setStreamHandler(self)
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

extension AppDelegate: FlutterStreamHandler {
    func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
        eventSink = events
        if eventSink == nil {
            return nil
        }
//        print("OnListen => \(eventSink)")
        eventSink!("Flutter onListen \(self.authNumber)")
        return nil
    }
    
    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        eventSink = nil
        return nil
    }
    
    
}
```

Say I have an onAuthNumber listener in swift, how do I make the eventSink listen to the changes in onAuthNumber listener. Thank you.